# add subview to UITableViewcell for making custom tableviewrowactions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

am trying to imitate the iOS mail application row action and its animation .I want to give support for devices below iOS 10.I tried with pan gesture and setted the frame of the cell and now I want to add subview to the cell right side and  animate it .Am not able to add subview to the right side of the tableview cell.[tableview cell when panned left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUvKv.jpg)

I tried setting the subview frame as follows 
  let view = UIView()
        print("maximum x position of the cell (cell.contentView.frame.maxX)")
        view.frame = CGRect(x: (cell.contentView.frame.maxX), y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: cell.frame.height)

Comment: try this library: https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

Comment: @YoCoh the third party libraries are unstable in my case so  i want to try on my own

Comment: this specific library is unstable, or all third party libraries? Meaning, you're not using any 3rd party libraries at all?

Comment: @YoCoh i need to support till iOS 8 so i can't use swipe cell kit so i have tried MGSWIPE table cell which is unstable in certain aspects .so i decided to write my own code .if you know any concepts please share it

Comment: right now i have positioned the cell but it need to show the options i tried it but subview is not displayed properly

Comment: I see ... I would probably look at how it's implemented in MGSwipe or SwipeCellKit and try to take inspiration from them.